# Scipy test fail after install. Is it bad?

Tags: scipy

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_io.test_imread
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 146, in skipper_func
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/tests/test_io.py", line 16, in test_imread
    assert_array_equal(img.shape, (300, 420, 3))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 707, in assert_array_equal
    verbose=verbose, header='Arrays are not equal')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 600, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal

(shapes (2,), (3,) mismatch)
 x: array([300, 420])
 y: array([300, 420,   3])

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4272 tests in 28.037s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=12, SKIP=20, failures=1)
```

Comment: Duplicate (and answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239989/error-when-testing-scipy