# python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()" failed

Tags: python, scipy

I installed python-numpy and python-scipy on ubuntu 12.10 (64-bits system)
and when I tried to test them using the commands 
***python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"
 python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"***
The first test goes well, but I got the following error with the second test with many warning messages.

```
FAIL: test_io.test_imread
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 146, in skipper_func
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/tests/test_io.py", line 16, in test_imread
    assert_array_equal(img.shape, (300, 420, 3))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 718, in assert_array_equal
    verbose=verbose, header='Arrays are not equal')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 599, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal

(shapes (2,), (3,) mismatch)
 x: array([300, 420])
 y: array([300, 420,   3])

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5103 tests in 50.510s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=13, SKIP=17, failures=1)
```

Comment: Looks like the `theano` tag could be removed--it doesn't appear in the question.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Sorry, my comment should have been a question:  Why does this question have a `theano` tag?  There are three tags: `python`, `scipy` and `theano`, but `theano` is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: That is because the installation follows the instructions of Easy installation of Theano    http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html

Comment: I don't know why, but I already saw this error. This error is in the scipy.ndimage for the io. As I don't use it, I didn't digged the answer. Maybe updating scipy to the latest release would solve this: pip install -U scipy

Comment: Probably issue in the version of PIL shipped with that version of ubuntu.

Comment: Have a look here for a detailed answer : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239989/error-when-testing-scipy